# Network design with reachability pattern

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

We are given two sets of terminals $A$ and $B$. For each $a\in A$, we are also given $R_a\subseteq B$. Let $|A|+|B|=n$.

We want to find a directed acyclic graph $G$ where $A$ and $B$ are subsets of the vertices, such that $a\in A$ can reach $b\in B$ if and only if $b\in R_a$. We want to optimize the number of edges.

I'm pretty sure this is studied somewhere, but I can't find the right keyword to search for it.

Comment: A problem that is closely related is that finding [the minimum equivalent graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction).  Given a directed graph, find a subgraph on the same vertex set, with the exact same reachability relations (between all pairs of vertices), and having the fewest possible edges.

Comment: The if and only if condition probably makes the problem very hard to approximate. Although not directly related I would suggest looking at the hardness  of approximation of the directed Steiner network problem in the paper of Dodis and Khanna. https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/301250.301447